# HTML Drop-Down submenu links will not work on high zoom

Tags: css, html

working on a HTML & CSS Drop Down navigation bar. Everything works fine besides, when you zoom in quite a bit, to the point where there will be 2 rows of menu links, the first rows submenus will stop working. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/negjq6pc/

When you rezise the result window to the point where there will be 2 rows of menu links, you cannot click on first row submenus.

I've tried changing the css values of the drop down lists, and I tried changing the menu layout to mobile, before it reaches the point where there will be 2 rows of drop down links but it did not end working.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class="logo_tekst"><a href='#'>FRENS CATERING</a></li>

            <li><a href='#'></a></li>

            <li class='active has-sub'>
                <a href='#'>NAVMENU1<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU2</a></li>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU2</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href='#'>NAVMENU3<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU4</a></li>

            <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU5</a></li>

            <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU6</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href='#'>NAVMENU7<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li`'s are `position: relative`, so they will have a default `z-index`, and that is higher than the nested sub-menu's. To make the sub-menu's clickable in their expanded state over the `li`'s that come below it, add a `z-index` to the sub-menu.

```css
body {
  font-family: MrEaves, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  user-select: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009ae1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #009ae1;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li,
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo_tekst {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class="logo_tekst"><a href='#'>FRENS CATERING</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href='#'></a>
    </li>

    <li class='active has-sub'>
      <a href='#'>NAVMENU1<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU2</a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU2</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href='#'>NAVMENU3<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU4</a></li>

    <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU5</a></li>

    <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU6</a></li>

    <li>
      <a href='#'>NAVMENU7<span class="arrow"> &#11167;</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>SUBMENU1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href='#'>NAVMENU8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried adding a z-index but I guess I added it to the wrong part. Much appriciated!